# How do I get the body of a PUT request in SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python, http.server

I have this super simple HTTP server to test some REST endpoints:

```
import http.server

class MyHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_PUT(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(409)
        self.end_headers()

server_address = ('', 8000)
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, MyHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

But, now I want to check if my PUT call sends the correct body, so I want to just print the request body in the `do_PUT` method. I tried looking for more info in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler), but it doesn't even mention the `do_PUT` method in the `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` class (or any other class for that matter).

How can I access the request body in the `do_PUT` method of a inherited `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it similarly to accessing a POST request's body

```py
import http.server


class MyHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_PUT(self):
        content_len = self.headers.get("Content-Length")
        if content_len is not None:
            body = self.rfile.read(int(content_len))
            print(body)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(409)
        self.end_headers()


server_address = ("", 8000)
httpd = http.server.HTTPServer(server_address, MyHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```